# Will a site that's been impacted by a spam action from Google no longer show up in it and its partner sites?

Tags: google-search, penalty

Is it true that a site impacted by an algorithmic or manual spam action may no longer show up in Google.com or its partner's sites?

I found an article on Webmaster Guidelines by Google [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769), and would like to know if others have found this to be the case or not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but what I can say is don't stuff a webpage with keywords only to the point where paragraphs don't make sense to a new user

Comment: Of course Google delists sites that it has determined to be spammy. It also effects the sites trust score for a very very long time. This means that even after Google decides that a site is no longer a spam site, and the site is listed again, it will not perform well in the SERPs because of the down-grade in the sites trust score.

Answer (score 1):

I don't realy get your question but if your question is all about algos of Google I say NO. If someone's site are hit by Google algo especially the penguin they must clean or delete the spam links and wait again for the release of next update of penguin to be get in the google ranking again.

Answer (score 1):

Completely de-listing a website from Google search (and partners) is possible, but usually only done for egregious spam sites that have little or no redeeming value. Google has a range of other penalties that they can apply to a site (most severe first):

- De-listing a website for all but brand and domain searches
- Introducing a negative ranking factor such that all rankings are worse
- Reducing ranking for specific terms and queries that have been "over optimized" or spammed